# Ignore form keys with initBinder

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc-initbinders

I was told there is a way for `initBinder` to ignore some keys passed in by a form.

So say I have a POJO with a `name`, `accountNumber`, and `balance`.

The user posts a form with an update to `accountNumber` with a new `balance`, but attempts to tamper with the form and adds a name to the post.

How do I ignore the name key and value from this form using `initBinder`?

edit: I feel like my bigger issue is the lack of understanding as to what `initBinder` actually does. So even helping me understand what that does could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DataBinder has two properties named `allowedFields` and `disallowedFields` that define what to (dis)allow for binding. Just use that in your `@InitBinde`r method:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setDisallowedFields("administrator");
}
```

Comment: Now I'm convince my issue is the lack of understanding of what `initBinder` is actually doing